# What's the best java method to keep a list of string values read from file

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I know it's a simple question but really want to see if there's another way to do it instead of using ArrayList to hold all the values. And if that's necessary, what should be the design of the java class.

Say I would need 5 list of values read from 5 files. Previously I just used 5 ArrayList to store the 5 list of values.

```
public class Values{
 ArrayList<String> o1 = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> o2 = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> o3 = new ArrayList<String>();
 ...

 public void readFromFile(ArrayList<String> listName, String filePath){
   /*read file contents into list*/
 }
```

But my problem is, each may contain more than 2000 string values. Is this an appropriate way to do so? If so, what would be a better design of it?

Comment: **Don't** store such amount of data in the memory.

Comment: @Braj why not? If is needed and you have the RAM to hold it, then where to store it?

Comment: There should be balance between memory uses and IO operation.

Comment: How do you plan on using/accessing the data once it's in memory?

Comment: @Braj: I processed a 5GB Twitter Streaming data using ArrayLists. I don't see anything wrong with it. I did it on a very slow machine with 2GB of RAM.

Comment: @Braj that's not a right approach. Your sentence is like we should not use cache nor in-memory databases.

Comment: What about third part cache such as `Infinispan` and `EHCache`?

Comment: @Braj they use RAM as well. Your first comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Do you need to retrieve all the data in order to process? If not then you should use something like a producer consumer model.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No worries I'll delete it if it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Braj Then what should I do or design the data structure?

Comment: @JudyJiang Do you need to store the data? or could you bypass that and access it directly from the file?

Comment: @Levenal I need the data. The thing is these string values are parts of sentences. i need to use them to reconstruct sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you really need to have that data in memory, there is nothing wrong with ArrayList to accomplish that. 5 files with 2000 strings of a length of 80 characters are 5*2000*80*2 bytes of character data + some overhead for the 10000 String objects + 5 ArrayList objects, in total you will use less than 1.7 MB of memory for that. Not a big deal.

You should change the declaration and use List instead of ArrayList, like this:

```
List<String> o1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In this way you can use for example a LinkedList instead of the ArrayList without changing to much of your code. But as long as you don't have any specific reason to use something else, go ahead and use the ArrayList, it is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will be fine with using ArrayLists for such a task. I have processed a large dataset of Tweets (aka Twitter Streaming data) to the tune of 5 GB and 1.5 million individual tweets. It wasn't an issue.

You can always increase your heap size if you have problems. Do realize that unless you really need to create and store so many ArrayLists, you can always clear them after intermediate processing.

```
java -Xms2048M -Xmx4096M YourProgramName
```

I think this should give you an idea of how you should design your program. The idea here is to add, process, remove. For my case, I just parsed, manipulated a tweet, cleared and moved on.

[image]

Comment: Yes this method is an option, but I'm thinking if there's a better design of doing so or holding data

Comment: Here's the deal. If you run into problems, come back and tell us and we can help you optimize your program better. Unless it doesn't face bottlenecks, we won't ever know if it is good or bad. With a positive mindset, give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Unless a different solution enhances testability, maintainability, clarity and simplicity of what you're trying to accomplish, go with what you have.  Writing good, clean code is much more important at the outset than writing highly optimized, fast performing code.  Clean code is code that's easy to optimize later anyway.

Comment: I love the KISS principle. :)